# Помощь в получение данных из подзапроса в бд SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос, подзапрос

Не понимаю, как выполнить данный запрос на основе моих таблиц.
Получите общее число палат и коек указанной больницы в общем и по каждому отделению, а также число свободных коек по каждому отделению и число полностью свободных палат.
Первую часть запроса я выполнил, найти общее количество коек и палат не составило труда, однако  число коек и палат по каждому отделению больницы найти одним запросом не получается, аналогично с числом свободных палат. Такие запросы мне удалось получить:
**###Общее число палат и коек указанной больницы**

```js
    ###Общее число палат и коек указанной больницы 
SELECT(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM koyka INNER JOIN palata on koyka.id_Palata=palata.id_Palata INNER JOIN department On palata.id_Department=department.id_Department inner JOIN hospital on department.id_Hospital=hospital.id_Hospital WHERE hospital.id_Hospital=1) as KoykaCountInHospital,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM palata INNER JOIN department On palata.id_Department=department.id_Department inner JOIN hospital on department.id_Hospital=hospital.id_Hospital WHERE hospital.id_Hospital=1) as PalataCountInHospital;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не могу разобраться как мне получить отделения, которые содержаться в данной больнице и затем по ним каким-то образом пройтись и проверить их на количество коек и палат. Такая же ситуация с полностью свободными палатами, мне нужно получить все палаты данного отделения и затем проверить каждую койку палаты данного отделения свободна ли она, и только в этом случае считать её в SELECT COUNT
Заранее спасибо!

[image: Таблица койка]

[image: Таблица палата]

[image: Таблица Отделений]

Comment: Не используйте скриншоты вашего кода, предоставьте код SQL запросов и/или структуру таблиц в текстовом виде

Comment: Для большей информативности, покажите схему используемых таблиц ( как они  взаимосвязаны )

Answer (score 0):

"Получите общее число палат и коек указанной больницы в общем и по каждому отделению":
Чтобы получить "по каждому отделению", можно включить в SELECT id-Department (или  Name) и использовать группировку GROUP BY по нему.